# copy data from one relation to another in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have 2 relations:

relation A:

```
101,Ankit-Reddy,08022017
102,Siddarth-Battacharya,08022017
103,Rajesh-Khanna,08022017
```

and Relation B:

```
102,Ronit-Roy,09022017
103,Ranveer-Singh,09022017
107,sadiya-some,09022017
108,Raj-sharma,09022017
```

so in ID 102 and 103 in B holds different date and it is an existing record but 107,108 are new records so it will remain same.
How can i update it to date in A.

My final table should look like:

```
101,Ankit-Reddy,08022017
102,Ronit-Roy,08022017
103,Ranveer-Singh,08022017
107,sadiya-some,09022017
108,Raj-sharma,09022017
```

Any pig script for this.

Answer (score 0):

- Get only records in A say A1
- Get only records in B say B1
- Join A and   B and create a record with a1,b2,a3 say C1
- Merge A1,B1,C1

  ```
  A = LOAD 'test1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a1:int,a2:chararray,a3:chararray);
  B = LOAD 'test2.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (b1:int,b2:chararray,b3:chararray);

  A_JOIN = JOIN A BY a1 LEFT OUTER,B BY b1;
  A1 = FILTER A_JOIN BY b1 is null;

  B_JOIN  = JOIN A BY a1 RIGHT OUTER,B BY b1;
  B1 = FILTER B_JOIN BY a1 is null;

  C_JOIN = JOIN A BY a1,B by b1;
  C1 = FOREACH C_JOIN GENERATE a1,b2,a3;

  D = UNION A1,B1,C1;
  ```

**A1**

```
101,Ankit-Reddy,08022017
```

**B1**

```
107,sadiya-some,09022017
108,Raj-sharma,09022017
```

**C1**

```
102,Ronit-Roy,08022017
103,Ranveer-Singh,08022017
```